# Making an array (list) with objects from an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is an object

```
{code: "HD", id: 211, name: "Spare parts for special equipment"}
```

I need to get it like this

```
{0: {code: "HD", id: 211, name: "Spare parts for special equipment"}}
```

What to do to get an array with objects, in this case, consisting of one object (the one above)?

Comment: Just wrap it in square brackets `[ .. ]`.

Comment: @Taplar I updated the question

Comment: ^^^ Use an array rather than an array like object

Comment: @Titus 
I am getting this programmatically

Comment: Then use `o = [o]`. Where `o` is the variable that references the object.

Comment: @Taplar I need this for my api

Comment: `var x = { '0': otherVariable }` then.